# Giving npm path to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, npm

I am starting to learn, how `npm` works. I installed the angularjs material. I see that inside the node module my module has been installed . My question is how can i Import that to html ? What I meant is how can i know which css or javascript file i need to insert into my template (html). Also will the npm module be recognize when i put in the ftp and when its live in browser ?

So what i have tried is

```
npm install angular-material
```

I also see the folder name `npm module`

Comment: Generally it would be in the dist folder, but while using npm we generally use requirejs to import js components instead of direct path to index.html.

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal can you show me some example. if you dont mind please

Comment: Nodejs is a framework, so there a lot of tools you can use, one of them being requirejs. You have to learn a few things before you can properly utilize the benefits. I suggest go through webpack or gulp build tool.